# Sorting and moving elements into a new element

Tags: xslt, sorting, element

Even with all the good tips on this site, I still have some trouble with my xslt. I'm pretty new to it. I have this source file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file>
  <id>1</id>
  <row type="A">
    <name>ABC</name>
  </row>
  <row type="B">
    <name>BCA</name>
  </row>
  <row type="A">
    <name>CBA</name>
  </row>
</file>
```

and I want to add an element and sort the rows on type, to get this result

```
<file>
  <id>1</id>
  <details>
  <row type="A">
    <name>ABC</name>
  </row>
    <row type="A">
      <name>CBA</name>
    </row>
  <row type="B">
    <name>BCA</name>
  </row>
  </details>
</file>
```

I'm able to sort the rows using this:

```
  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*/row"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="@type" data-type="text"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

and I'm able to move the rows using this

```
 <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(name(.)='row')]" />
      <details>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="row"  />
      </details>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

but I'm not able to produce the correct answer when I try to combine them. Hopefully I understand more of XSLT when I see how things are combined. Since I'm creating a new element `<details>`, I think the sorting has to be done before the creation of the new `<details>` element. I have to use xslt 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this seems to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="row[1]/preceding-sibling::*" />
      <details>
        <xsl:for-each select="row">
          <xsl:sort select="@type" data-type="text"/>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </details>
      <xsl:copy-of select="row[last()]/following-sibling::*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the result I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file>
  <id>1</id>
  <details>
    <row type="A">
      <name>ABC</name>
    </row>
    <row type="A">
      <name>CBA</name>
    </row>
    <row type="B">
      <name>BCA</name>
    </row>
  </details>
</file>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works fine, and I understood your solution :) It was easy to reuse on other files.